What Do The New Geometry Nodes Pink Colored Rotation Sockets in 4.1 mean?
I was just working on a project and happened to notice that the input to the rotation for the Instance on Points in 4.1 is no longer a blue socket as it was previously. It is now purplish in color, although the Scale socket is still blue.
I wanted to know what this represents.

Previously both Rotation and Scale were blue, as they are vector field inputs. What has changed now? I could not find anything in the manual.

There's a good YT video explaining all the node types and colours in Blender 4.1 here.

@JohnEason That's a really good explanation video! Thanks for sharing. But in the video I couldn't find the information the OP was looking for regarding what the new purple color represented

Introduced in Blender 4.0 there are new Rotation sockets (look for Simpler Rotations), which replace the old blue colored Vector sockets for the specific cases of rotation values.

Functionally they should be the same, but there are now specific nodes to deal with rotation as presented in the manual which make it simpler to work with rotations by specifying axis, angles, or quaternions, rather than vector values.
Existing nodes have since been slowly but surely converted to use the new pink colored socket for operations that deal with rotation, rather than more general vectors. In this instance for:


Distribute Points on Faces
Instance on Points
Rotate Instances
Transform Geometry


As stated in the commit Geometry Nodes: Convert four nodes to use rotation socket
